How to verify that a block of text on a page includes the ® symbol?
I'm creating an automation test for a series of webpages for work. One of the tasks is to verify the text of a block at the bottom of a webpage matches acceptance criteria. We use Selenium and Java to execute our automation tests. I can point the automation to the location I want with the XPath, and I can get it to read/validate half of the block, but my problem is the block of text contains the ® symbol after the company name in the element. The element on the web page reads something like this:
<div class="form-group"> == $0
    ::before
    <div id="alerts-message" class="dynamic-message-wrap">
        <p>
            "The first half of the legal jargon here. The company name"
            <sup>®</sup>
            " has even more legal jargon after. Or click here to view our "
            <a href="URL" target="_blank"> == $0
                "Terms&npsp;&&npbp;Conditions"
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
    ::after
</div>

I want to verify that says:

"The first half of the legal jargon here. The company name® has even more legal jargon after. Or click here to view our Terms & Conditions."

How can I use our automation to validate the entire text of this block when it's broken up in the page element like that?
I usually use something like
let termsAndConditions = await this.webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(<xpath>[contains(text(),"Text I'm looking to validate")])).isDisplayed();
expect(termsAndConditions).toBe(true);

but that's not working here because of the breakup caused by the <sup>®</sup> and hyperlink in the element. Is there a way to validate this based on the text the user sees on the page instead of that HTML?

Post the relevant HTML as text, properly formatted. Also, that code is not valid and won't compile. Post the actual code you are using and the error message as text, properly formatted.

The code is not complete. I pulled out just the relevant snippet I usually use to look for text on a web page as an example of what I've tried that didn't work. I did update the post though with the relevant HTML

That HTML is not valid and you still haven't fixed your code... it's still invalid as well.

the text() method should return displayed text only.  Not sure why this wouldn't work except that you may need multiple locators for different bits and/or nested text/element nodes.

You just need to pull the text from the DIV and then Assert that it's the same as whatever the expected text is.
Sample code
String expectedText = "Whatever the expected text is";
String actualText = driver.findElement(By.id("alerts-message")).getText();

Assert.assertEquals(actualText, expectedText);

